# NDSolve`ProcessEquations inside Manipulate

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, manipulate

`NDSolve` and `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` can handle equations with vectors on each side like this one:

```
x1 = {1, 0};
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
  {{x'[t], y'[t]} == {-y[t], x[t]}, {x[0], y[0]} == x1},
  {x, y}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
(*  {NDSolve`StateData[<0.>]}  *)
```

However, when it occurs inside a `Manipulate`, `NDSolve` works fine, but `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` fails:

```
Manipulate[
 {Check[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
    {{x'[t], y'[t]} == {-y[t], x[t]}, {x[0], y[0]} == x0},
    {x, y}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], $MessageList],
  Check[NDSolve[
    {{x'[t], y'[t]} == {-y[t], x[t]}, {x[0], y[0]} == x0},
    {x, y}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], $MessageList]},
 {{x0, {1, 0}}, InputField}
 ]
```

[image]

They both have the same attributes, namely `{Protected}`.  The message `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations::ndnco `` is the message that both `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` and `NDSolve` give if `x0` does not evaluate to a `List`.

So that seems like a hint, but why do the two behave differently?

Comment: I don't know the significance, but `Thread[{x[0], y[0]} == x0]` in ``NDSolve`ProcessEquations`` fixes the problem.